# Passing Data from ViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

### Help me to understand what I am missing please?

Storyboard setup:

**ViewController -> TabBarController -> NavigationController which contains a TableViewController**

There is a segue with Identifier "*startUp*" from the **ViewController** to the **TabBarController**

The **ViewController** is the Initial Entry Screen.
The **ViewController** has a **SegmentedControl** and a **Button**

USAGE: User selects one of the segments and presses the button. The view should segue to the TableViewController and replace the NavigationItem.Title with the title from the SegmentedControl segment which was selected.

PROBLEM: The data is not being passed from the ViewController to the TableViewController (and through the TabBarController and NavigationController). I am always ending up with a blank Header Title on the TableViewController. I have walked carefully through a couple dozen 'how-tos' over the past few days both here and other locations on the web using segue and other methods. At this point nothing seems to work and I'm dizzy (and probably missing something really, really basic).

Here is the way the code currently 'sits'

ViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var someData: String? = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var cpChoice: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func startBut(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "startUp", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let theIndex = cpChoice.selectedSegmentIndex
        someData = cpChoice.titleForSegment(at: theIndex)

        print(someData!) //outputs correctly to console

        if segue.destination is CheckpointVC
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as? CheckpointVC
            vc?.data = someData!
        }
    }
}
```

TableViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class CheckpointVC: UITableViewController {

    var data: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var theHeader: UINavigationItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = data
        //theHeader.title = data
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

> PIECE DEFINITIONS

[image: The pieces]

> 

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var someData: String? = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var cpChoice: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func startBut(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "startUp", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        //get the string representing the segment chosen and assign it to someData
        let theSegmentChosen = cpChoice.selectedSegmentIndex
        someData = cpChoice.titleForSegment(at: theSegmentChosen)


        let barVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController //
        let navigationControllerDestination = barVC.viewControllers?[0] as? navVC //the array index [0] indicates the first view controller belonging to the TabBarController
        let firstViewControllerOfNavigationController = navigationControllerDestination?.topViewController as! CheckpointVC
        firstViewControllerOfNavigationController.data = someData!
    }
}
```

> 

**TabBarVC**

```
import UIKit

class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

> 

**NavVC**

```
import UIKit

class navVC: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

> 

**CheckpointVC.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CheckpointVC: UITableViewController {

    //the variable we'll pass the data to from the starting viewcontroller
    var data: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var theHeader: UINavigationItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        theHeader.title = data
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you breakpoint on the segue to actually check if segue.destination is CheckpointVC? The solution has been right in front of your eyes all along. Since you have setup the viewcontrollers as such...

```
ViewController -> TabBarController -> NavigationController which contains a TableViewController
```

Your segue.destination is technically TabBarController unless the segue with identifier `startUp` leads to TableViewVC.

A short way to solve it is to unwrap the TableVC from your TabBarVC as such:

```
(tabBarVC.viewControllers[indexOfYourNavVC] as? NavigationController).viewControllers.first as? TableVC)
```

The longer but cleaner way of doing it is to implement a routing pattern from this blog. Sorry to say that I myself am still learning about this so I can only recommend websites to start with:
https://clean-swift.com/routing-in-clean-swift/

Comment: OK... you have a point there. When setting a breakpoint inside 'if segue.destination is CheckpointVC', the breakpoint never fires. The segue does go to TabBarController first... which then passes through to the NavigationController and ends on the TableViewController (CheckpointVC). But that leaves me wondering what best practice is for passing the 'someData' var all the way through to CheckpointVC?

Comment: I have updated my answer to help solve your issue (hopefully you find it helpful yourself) @craab

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the segue target to a Navigation Controller Which contain your CheckpointVC as a root view controller.